# What is a single word for "Out of our control"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that defines that something is out of our control in a business sense. For example, we can't control the postal delivery time, so it is... (out of our control).
Needs to be ONE word, please.

EDIT - not uncontrollable. It is also not chaotic, like "the children are out of control".

EDIT2: - to further explain, in my thesis I have a number of dependencies. Most of them our company can control as we manage them. However, a few of these dependencies we are not able to control because they are managed by someone else. So I'm looking to see if there is a word that can explain this other than saying "dependencies that are out of our control".

Comment: Uncontrollable?

Comment: These sound like *external* factors.

Comment: I don't think you've made a compelling case for limiting yourself (and us!) to one word (after reading edit 2).  Unfortunately, most of the single words that literally mean "not capable of being controlled" also have the inconvenient connotation of being wild or chaotic.  It sounds like you need to keep a neutral tone; so you are stuck with using multiple words (not horrible, in my opinion) or actually @onomatomaniak's *external*.  "External dependencies" is not too far from "external factors"....

Comment: _External factors_ is good.

Comment: As a follow-up to my earlier comment, if what's being sought is a stand-alone noun, OP could use *externals* or *externalities.*

Comment: _External factors_ is good.

Comment: _External factors_ is two words.

Comment: The word you're looking for is bureaucracy!

Answer (score 4):

If something is not in your control, it could be:

- ***"independent"***
- ***"autonomous"***
- ***"free" (of your control)***
- ***"sovereign"***
- ***"uncontrolled" (which is different that uncontrollable)***

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, unbiddable and self-regulating work for me too, but "unharnessable" sounds like something out of everyone's control, not just ours (like a runaway horse!) :-)

Comment: unharnessable, ungovernable,unmanageable, unbiddable, self-regulating ...

Comment: Sorry I've destroyed sensible order - I just missed the 5-min deadline. I'd say 'unharnessable' _does_ connote wildness, and perhaps that _is_ a descriptor a bit unfair to saddle the postal services with. Some of our local services, though ...? Notice that we're talking about services alleged to serve here - I wouldn't call a lion 'unharnessable'. Then again, I'd choose 'beyond our control' here.

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing a contract, I think there are multi-word possibilities your attorneys can supply, but the one word I can think of closest to what you want is *exogenous*.

Comment: It's not *exactly* the same as "out of our control", but I'd say it's a reasonable stretch.  If you were to use this word where you would otherwise use "out of our control", I think people would get what you mean.

Comment: I thought exogenous relates to things biological?

Comment: @AndrewFindlay: Usually used there, but not _exclusively._ It also has regular use in anthropology. I don't think it's a science term-of-art. If there were one perfect word, someone would probably have posted it already.

Answer (score 3):

*Chaos* might be the word you're looking for. Also, *chaotic*, the adjectival form of *chaos*.

EDIT:

*Amok*, *haywire*, and *wild* are other suggestions.

EDIT 2:

*Wild* could still apply in some cases. However, perhaps you are looking for *independent*? I don't believe so, but it is the closest word I can think of at the moment that applies.

Comment: no, that is not it

Comment: no, this is not the right context. Here's another example - the sun rises every day. it is out of control, it is not chaotic or the other suggestions. It should mean we have no control over how something happens

Comment: Saying 'sun is out of control' also does not make any sense.

Comment: I believe he means, "The Sun is out of *our* control".

Answer (score 2):

*[Inevitable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inevitable#Adjective)* has two senses that might work well:

> 1. Impossible to avoid or prevent. [eg] We were going so fast that the collision was inevitable.
> 2. Predictable, or always happening. [eg] My outburst met with the inevitable punishment.

In a business context you might speak of a *[foregone conclusion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foregone_conclusion)* (“A predictable or inevitable conclusion...”).

*[Predetermined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predetermined)*, simple past tense and past participle of *[predetermine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predetermine#Verb)* (“To determine or decide in advance”) might also work.

Also *[fated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fated#Adjective)* (“Foreordained, predetermined, established in advance by fate”).

I think *[foreordain](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foreordain#Verb)* (“To predestine or preordain”) is seen less commonly than is  *[preordain](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preordain#Verb)* (“To determine the fate of something in advance”).  Forms of the verbs  *predetermine*,  *predestine*,  *foreordain*, *preordain* and in some cases *[ordain](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ordain#English)* (in sense “to prearrange unalterably” or in sense “to predestine”), often are used of things that are avolitional, that is, not under the control of whatever parties are involved.

Also consider *[mandatory](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mandatory#Adjective)* (“Obligatory; required or commanded by authority”), *[involuntary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/involuntary#Adjective)* (“Not voluntary or willing...”),  and *[obligatory](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obligatory#Adjective)*.

Answer (score 1):

Intractable

is one possibility (having to type 30 chars for a one word answer is a very tractable UI issue for SO).

Comment: Use those characters to flesh out your answer. For instance, link to a definition, provide relevant usage examples, or explain why you think it's a suitable word.

Answer (score 0):

I am tempted to think of "unregulable" as the word you are looking for, though it is an uncommon word and few dictionaries list it.

Answer (score 0):

Independent variables affecting your system from the outside are *inputs*. Input parameters which are quasi-constant (do not change often) are *given*. E.g. you don't control some tax rate, but it is given. It does not fluctuate, like mail delivery times.

An external influence is *imposed*. (We are forced to accomodate to it, rather than manipulating it to suit our convenience).

"We don't control the tax rate; it is {*given* / *imposed* (on us)}."

"We can't control postal delivery times, they are *imposed* (on us)."