# Synonyms of noun "uncontrollableness" (or related adjective)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a better word for "uncontrollableness"? 
After significant googling I have come up short of -- to me -- an appropriate answer.

Is there such a word? I'm looking in the context of "...To suggest the weather's "uncontrollableness"" -- or some other arrangement, but can't find a suitable direct synonym.

Comment: Weather is often described as *capricious*, *mercurial*, or *fickle*, but that captures its inherent unpredictability, not necessarily its uncontrollability. But nevertheless these words might be suitable entry points for a deeper thesaurus search.

Comment: Unwieldiness? Intractability? Also: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/intractable

Comment: If you change the point of view, you can get the desired meaning by saying, "We are impotent against the weather."  Or you can talk about our impotence to change the weather.

Comment: Well, *controllability* is a word, so why not [*uncontrollability*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncontrollable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the characteristics are adjectives and don't easily turn into pretty/accepted nouns.
**Weather is primitive**
Or **weather remains intractable**.

If you are desperate for a noun situation, perhaps use the adjective to modify a placeholder noun such like nature or character.
**untamed nature**
or **unstable nature**
or **stubborn nature**.

If you do want actual nouns, perhaps a few useful options remain.  Here are some options that appear in dictionaries... but don't have their own definition given apart from the adjectives...

**wildness**

> living in a state of nature and not ordinarily tame or domesticated ([m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wildness))

Or **tempestuousness**

> tumultuous; turbulent ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tempestuous))

Comment: See also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111033/what-is-a-single-word-for-out-of-our-control) for some other options.

Answer (score 1):

How about **unpredictability**?

OD:

> [**unpredictability**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unpredictability): Inability to be predicted; changeability.
>   *‘the unpredictability of the British weather’*

Something that cannot be predicted cannot be controlled.

Comment: That is true of weather, but you put a baby in a crib to control him because you cannot predict what he will do when your back is turned.  At least I think that is what a crib is for.

Comment: @ab2 Just because you put a baby in a crib doesn't mean you control the baby totally. Of course, you could let the baby cry themself to sleep, etc., but have you really controlled them? Plus, unlike other phenomena, such as weather. babies are relatively predictable.