# What is the word for events that we can not control

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to find a noun for event or set of events that we can not change or control.
Is there any word that fits the meaning?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Why *uncontrollable events* shouldn't be used?

Comment: This would be informed if not dictated by one's world-view.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111033/what-is-a-single-word-for-out-of-our-control?rq=1)

Comment: Do you really mean *events you are able to not control* (**can** not control, as you have it), or do you mean *events you are unable to control* (**cannot** control)?

Comment: My bad, I need to find a word for events that we are unable to control.
I remember reading this word somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: Have you considered ***fate**?*

Answer (score 3):

A common term for events 'out of our control' is *"[force majeure](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/force-majeure)"*, with some further examples on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_majeure).

This term is especially common in the insurance industry, where it is used as an 'escape' clause to avoid paying out on insurance claims, for natural disasters such as earthquakes and tsunamis, and in the legal industry, where a party could attempt to claim *force majeure* to get out of an adverse clause.

Historically, Western countries have also referred to such events as *"[an act of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_of_God)"*.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a short saying, like "uncontrollable circumstances". "Disaster" depending on the topic, of course.